# Control-drag in Xcode provides constraint options instead of IBOutlet options

Tags: xcode

I've added a new `IBOutlet` that I want to connect in Interface Builder - however, all of a sudden, control-dragging from the class to the interface item provides me with a list of constraint options instead of a list of outlets/received actions.

This does not seem to affect all items, only some of them, but I've double-checked both the designated class of the cell view, as well as the `@IBOutlet` declaration in the source file, and everything seems to match up properly:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work around this issue by simply right-clicking on the source item (without dragging), and then connecting the individual outlets in the list.